# How to duplicate item multiple times based on value?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, duplicate, whencreated

I want to duplicate a newly created item multiple times based on the users input of how many. In SPD, I know how to create a single duplicate but how does one go about creating multiple duplicates like this?

Comment: If you're using SPD 2013 workflows you should be able to do it using the Loop block...

Answer (score 2):

For SharePoint 2013 workflow,Create a custom field to record duplicate count so you could use it.

Simple demo:

[image]

[image]